# Create encryption and decryption program

Tags: python, encryption

I need someone to edit my code to debug it. It won't display any of the encrypted or decrypted text which I think is because the formatting is messed up but I don't know. If you could help that'd be greatly appreciated. (I have to include functions and user input)

```
result = ''
text = ''


text = input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt the message?\n 1 to encrypt, 2 to decrypt or 0 to exit program. ")
def toList(text):
  text.split()
  return text

decrypted = b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
encrypted = b"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM "

encrypt_table = bytes.maketrans(decrypted, encrypted)
decrypt_table = bytes.maketrans(encrypted, decrypted)

text = input('Enter message for encryption: ')
def encrypt(text):
  result = ''
  text = ''
  result = text.translate(encrypt_table)
  print(result + '\n\n')


cipherText = input('Enter message to decrypt: ')
def decrypt(cipherText):
    result = ''
    message = ''
    result = message.translate(decrypt_table)
    print(result + '\n\n')


if text == '1':
  encrypt(text)
  print(result + '\n\n')
elif text == '2':
  decrypt(cipherText)

elif text != '0':
  print('You have entered an invalid input, please try again. \n\n')
```

Comment: You keep reusing the variable `text`.  By the time you get to `if text=='1':`, `text` no longer contains 0 or 1.  I believe you want the second and third `input` statements to be INSIDE those functions.

Comment: Also, in your `encrypt` function you clear the parameter before trying to encrypt it - so what you're doing is encrypting the empty string

Comment: And in `decrypt` you take a `cipherText` parameter but once again you `translate()` the empty string `message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had quite a number of confusions.  Look at `encrypt`, for example.  You pass in `text`, then you immediately set `text=''`, thereby destroying the message that was input.  Similarly, in `decrypt`, you pass in `cipherText`, but you run `message.translate`.  And your functions need to return their results, not print them.  Let the caller decide what to do with the returned results.

Also, it is a good practice to collect your functions at the top of the module, so you don't fool yourself into believing that things get called in the wrong order.

Here is your code, modified so that it works:

```
def encrypt(text):
    result = text.translate(encrypt_table)
    return result

def decrypt(message):
    result = message.translate(decrypt_table)
    return result

decrypted = b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
encrypted = b"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM "

encrypt_table = bytes.maketrans(decrypted, encrypted)
decrypt_table = bytes.maketrans(encrypted, decrypted)

while True:
    text = input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt the message?\n 1 to encrypt, 2 to decrypt or 0 to exit program. ")

    if text == '1':
        text = input('Enter message for encryption: ')
        result =  encrypt(text)
        print(result)
    elif text == '2':
        cipherText = input('Enter message to decrypt: ')
        result = decrypt(cipherText)
        print(result)
    elif text == '0':
        break
    else:
        print('You have entered an invalid input, please try again. \n\n')
```

Note that `encrypt` and `decrypt` don't really need to store in a temporary variable.  The only reason to do that is because it is more convenient for debugging, to add a quick `print(result)` before the `return`.